# Is blocking / allowing by IP using .htaccess (or equivalent) enough to secure a resource on a web server?

Tags: networking, security, ip, firewall, webserver

Currently in the process of setting up a web infrastructure to host my web application where security is the most important factor and I need to be able to allow only specific IP addresses to a specific resource/page within the site. What is the most secured approach, could this be achieved with a dedicated firewall for example as well as the .htaccess (or alike) approach?

Comment: sounds like you'd leave yourself open to spoofing attacks ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing

Comment: Thanks, will have to look into preventing this! Will also be having an authentication process in place...

Comment: "security is the most important factor" => hire a professional security person. Security measures that are enough today may be obsolete tomorrow.

Comment: @zimmi yes I will be but Id still like to get as much understanding as possible along with a development setup to start with before hand.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not enough (it is not useless but it is not enough):

If you deny access to a range of IP’s through `.htaccess`, but leave anywhere an open way of accessing the file system (example: FTP, or bad password, or code injection or …) then one can get in and change the `.htaccess`.

Giving more advice will be too broad according to the few information we have, that’s why I told you to get professional advice (possibly since the beginning of app development) and focus on [writing a secure app](http://www.google.com/search?q=writing%20secure%20web%20applications).